# Can I find out if variable is an array using Template Toolkit?

Tags: html, template-toolkit

I'm passing the results of a multi-select box to a page so that the selections can be shown on screen. As it's multi-select, the result can either be a scalar or an array reference. Is there a way of finding this out? I can't find anything online, but I thought there might be a `.array` or `.array_ref` token that could be used for validation.
I'm using Template Toolkit, Perl and Dancer.

So here is what I've got for a scalar:

```
<% IF multitext %>
    Text: <% multitext %>
<% END %>
```

What I want is something like...

```
<% IF multitext %>
    <% IF multitext.array_ref %> <!-- whatever works! -->
        <% FOREACH text IN multitext %>
            Text: <% text %>
        <% END %>
    <% ELSE %>
        Text: <% multitext %>
    <% END %>
<% END %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `<%- multitext.0 -%>` returns a non-zero value, it's an arrayref.

If `<%- multitext.keys.size -%>` returns a non-zero value, it's a hashref.

The way I usually handle it is to force it to be an array if it's a scalar, eg:

```
<%- SET items = multitext.0 ? multitext : [ multitext ];
    FOREACH item IN items;
        ...
    END; -%>
```

Comment: RET, your statement "If <%- multitext.size -%> ... returns a non-zero value, it's an arrayref", is not strictly correct. It may also be a hashref. According to the Template Toolkit documentation, using the 'size' method on a hash(ref) "returns the number of key/value pairs in the hash." multitext.0 works well, though.

Comment: Good point, Mauritz, although the question was specifically array or scalar value. I've amended the answer for the general case.

Comment: `<%- multitext.0 -%>` will return false (or zero) if the first element of the array is false (or zero), so it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: That's true, but it's also easily resolved if your `multitext` is an array of scalars where the first element could be blank/zero by using the `defined` method, e.g.: `[%- SET items = multitext.0.defined ? multitext : [ multitext ];`

Answer (score 0):

Several years later...

You could use the `.list` vmethod to guarantee it's an array e.g.

```
    <% FOREACH text IN multitext.list %>
        Text: <% text %>
    <% END %>
```

See http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_list